# How is the concept of "content negotiation" called outside the HTTP context?

Tags: computer-science, theory, naming, protocols, content-negotiation

What are different terms for "content negotiation" (when not talking about HTTP)?

For example: some (remote or local) services, components, modules,
are negotiating about which protocol to use and/or which content type to exchange.

**Service provider**

- About the content:

  - What I am very good at, is providing apples.
  - I am also able to provide bananas, but it takes me more time.
  - I am also able to provide oranges, but their quality is not always OK.
- About the protocol:

  - I can bring the fruits to you in a plastic bag.
  - Alternatively, I can throw it in your direction.
    It's faster, but some fruits may get lost.

**Service consumer**

- I need some fruits.
- Bananas are OK, but apples would be great!
- I need them now!
- Some may get lost.

Now, after using some negotiation protocol, the provider and the user decide that the optimal solution for them would be: "the *provider* throws to the *consumer* some apples".

*I hope you like my example ;)*

**So, what are better suited terms for what I am looking for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call this process, generically, "negotiation". That is the best word I know of in industry. I'd call this process a part of the broader protocol handshake and negotiation phase.